# Ajax, jQuery replacement

Tags: jquery

Using the html:

```
<div id="dynamic-choice">
<a href="http://www.google.com/" class="ajaxLink">click me</a>
<a href="a.nother/page/toload.html" class="ajaxLink">click me 2</a>
</div>

<div id="dynamic-content">
<p>this will be replaced</p>
</div>
```

and javascript

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a.ajaxLink').click(function(){
var url = $(this).attr('href');
$('#dynamic-content').empty().load(url);
});
return false;
});
</script>
```

However the anchors are just behaving as normal links :/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a.ajaxLink').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var url = $(this).attr('href');
$('#dynamic-content').empty().load(url);
});
```

is the working version of your code.

You have to passt the event `e` to use the preventDefault method, to prevent the anchors from acting normal !

**Documentation:**

[event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Comment: Okay, that change successfully stops the browser from following the link, and makes the dynamic content section disappear. It doesn't seem to do much else unfortunately. I probably have to specify additional parameters, as the would-be iframe section doesn't have any dimension declarations to work off, etc.